# Why is this simple conditional view code not working?

Tags: django, django-views

Models:

```
INTERNAL_STATES = (
    ('1', _('Live')),
    ('2', _('Coming soon')),
    ('3', _('Draft')),
)
```

View:

```
if request.user.is_staff is False and building.internal_state is not 1:
    raise Http404
else:
    pass
```

Can someone tell me why this code is landing me a 404 even if the building I am trying to view has internal_state = 1 when I am not logged in? Sorry for posting such an easy question but I just can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Try to avoid `is False`. It's better to use `if not request.user.is_staff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of internal_state is a string, not an integer.

Try this:

```
if not request.user.is_staff and building.internal_state != '1':
    raise Http404
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Don't use `is` for string comparisons.

Comment: You're right, I just was pointing same code than asker but with quotes. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with 'is' operator can be dangerous even with integer numbers. In CPython realization, you can check that if you type:

```
a = 1
b = 1
a is b
#True
```

but if you type something like this:

```
a = -6
b = -6
a is b
#False
```

It a matter of fact that 'is' operator compares not values but the addresses in memory.

That's my 50 cent.